# How to use GNU Makes dry run mode with CMake generated Makefile before actually performing the installation

Tags: makefile, cmake, installation, target

Every now and then a new tarball or a new xyHub/Lab-repository needs to be built. They usually come with a Makfile or an Autotools/CMake/XY-Generator provides one on the fly. As the maintainers most likely use another operating system or distribution than the one I am currently running, the assumptions that went into their Makefiles usually do not fit my filesystem hierarchy (lib vs. lib64, bin vs. sbin, /usr/lib vs. /lib and so on). As the final command in the build sequence usually is

```
sudo make install
```

it is quite annoying to move thousands of files to the correct place. Or even worse determine which files of my distribution were overwritten. Here GNU Makes dry run mode comes in very handy. Running

```
sudo make -n install
```

first, saves me the trouble of cleaning up my file system, by just printing all the commands from all active GNU Make recepies without executing them. In case of a handwritten or Autotools-generated Makfile this works as intended. If the Makefile contains something like:

```
#PREFIX is environment variable, but if it is not set, then set default value
ifeq ($(PREFIX),)
    PREFIX := /usr/local
endif

install: unixlib.a
    install -d $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install -m 644 unixlib.a $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install -d $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/include/
    install -m 644 unixlib.h $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/include/
```

I would see exactly what would happen. Every `install`/`cp`/`mv`-command with the full path information would be printed. If I made a mistake with the install prefix in the configure step I can see it there. If the default in the Makefile is weird because it comes from another OS, I would see it there.

Now in case of a CMake-generated Makefile this is different. Doing

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make -n install
```

only produces output that ends in

```
...
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_echo_color --switch= --cyan "Install the project..."
/usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
```

As these commands get not executed, just printed, I do not get all the `cp`/`mv`/`mkdir`/`install`/etc-commands that I would like to see first, before I let the Makefile touch the file system.

Is there a way to get the list of commands that would be executed from the install target in a CMake-generated Makefile as it is the case with handwritten or Autotools-generated ones?

Comment: If installing into local directory is acceptible to you, then you may use `make DESTDIR=<local-directory> install`. See more about this variable in CMake documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/envvar/DESTDIR.html.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the list of commands that would be executed from the install target.

Actually, the core part of installation process is contained in the file `cmake_install.cmake` (which is created in the build directory). This file is processed as **CMake script** using `cmake -P` flow of the [cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake.1.html) executable.

The script `cmake_install.cmake` performes installation of files with `install` command. Semantic of the `install` command, used by the script, differs from the one described in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/install.html): internally, CMake uses some undocumented features of the command.

But it shouldn't be so hard to understand `cmake_install.cmake` script in general and deduce paths from it.

Comment: Looking at cmake_install.cmake is no help. It just includes all the _install.cmake files from the subdirectories.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that hierarchical sctructure of CMake internal scripts. But I know no other way to explore installation actions without actually doing them.